# Is there a way to replace the Reading Pane with a VSTO CustomTaskBar in Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I have a custom task pane I've made in VSTO for Outlook 2007, but it needs a fair amount of screen real estate to be functional. I'd like to just take over the place of the Reading Pane, as it won't really be needed when this addon is active. It's also a really great spot since this addon relies on drag-and-drop from mail folders to this task pane, and the closer I can get it to the folder pane, the better.

Any way to replace the Reading Pane, or at least toggle it's visibility?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a way in OOM to do this .. I you can change the size of you region though.

I have seen it done though with add-in-express tool http://www.add-in-express.com but that may be 2 much work for you to change to that model.

Comment: Tell a lie I found this method on the explorer object ShowPane()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210298(office.11).aspx

Comment: Ah that really helps. So just for reference if needed one can minimize the preview pane by doing:

Application.ActiveExplorer().ShowPane(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPane.olPreview, false);

And to bring it back:

Application.ActiveExplorer().ShowPane(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPane.olPreview, true);

Comment: Yep, not sure thats what you wanted though ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Replacement or Replace All Form Region options. Both of these options allow to replace the display of form region.

The Replacement form region let's you build a custom first page of your own.
The Replace All form region let's you build all form pages.

These are not simple options as you must provide all Outlook capabilities the user expects. This is why the Adjoining form region option is the popular choice.

You can read more here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd492010(v=office.12).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb206784.aspx